# Azure VM Encryption: aadAppname

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-virtual-machine

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-disk-encryption

Following the above example to encrypt some VMs before they're purposed as DCs, I've hit a snag. While I can provide a resource group, `keyvault`, location and subscription ID, I'm a little nonplussed as to the app which interacts with the encryption.

According to the article, the script will ask for an "aadAppName", and will either use an existing one if it exists, or ask for a name to create one for you should none be found.

This portion of the script doesn't seem to pop up, and hence, I never receive the values of `aadClientID`, `aadClientSecret`, `diskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl`, and `keyVaultResourceId`, stopping me from running the final command to encrypt the VMs.

Any suggestions on how to move beyond this?

Answer (score 0):

Required parameter in script is set to false!

Answer (score 0):

The app is not specific, you have to create it and give it the right permission to keyvault.

I tried to break it down on this video I created about a year ago. Hope it helps.

https://youtu.be/k9byoc-_t7I

Comment: Hannel, oddly enough I found that video yesterday! Cheers.